# BitLocker on Hyper-V Server 2019 - Failed - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-core, bitlocker, tpm, hyper-v-server-2019

To start with, I want to be clear that this is on "Hyper-V Server 2019" (free headless hypervisor) and ***not*** "Windows Server 2019" with the Hyper-V role installed.

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one a while and tried just about every tutorial option I can. It's far too much to explain every one of the options I've tried. The short version is that no matter what I do to enable BitLocker in some manner or another I end up with an error about not being able to find a file like what is shown in brief here...

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\> Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -EncryptionMethod XtsAes256 -UsedSpaceOnly -RecoveryKeyPath "E:\" -RecoveryKeyProtector
Add-TpmProtectorInternal : The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\BitLocker\BitLocker.psm1:2095 char:31
```

I get the same error message if it's with a password, recovery key, TPM... makes no difference. I get a similar, but not as verbose of an error, when I use Manage-BDE.exe to attempt enabling BitLocker.

I've reformatted a few times. I've tried before and after domain join. Before/After feature add-ons. I've tried clearing the TPM on several occasions. I've tried having Secure Boot enabled/disabled in the BIOS. I've enabled/disabled/destroyed/rebuilt the Windows recovery partition as well as the ReAgent.xml file.

I'm basically out of options and looking for anything I can get for help. What I ultimately want it to do is boot from just the TPM and have the option for recovery password and optionally a recovery key.

Basic System Overview:

- Supermicro X10SRW-F
- E5-2690 v3
- 2 x 248GB Enterprise Samsung SSDs in Mirror (RAID 1) in BIOS (via Intel VROC)
- TPM 2.0
- UEFI Boot only (not dual or Legacy boot)
- Hyper-V Server 2019
- Roles: Hyper-V Role
- Features:

  - .NET 4.7
  - BitLocker
  - RSAT for BitLocker and Hyper-V
  - Standard for everything else (nothing above stock)
- Add-On: Installed Application Features on Demand to get Explorer, Powershell_ISE and a few other tools.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this link:

[troubleshoot bitlocker in Windows Server 2019 Core](https://www.teal-consulting.de/en/2019/11/12/troubleshooting-bitlocker-on-server-2019-core/?cookie-state-change=1592761447200)

It helped me solve it. It seems that Server Core App Compatibility produces the problem, after removing it you can proceed with bitlocker and later re-enable Server Core App Compatibility. There's also updated info from MS, with which you can avoid removing and re-enabling (I haven't tested the later).

Only difference in that you use the free of charge HyperV server, but you can give it a try.

Comment: I tested with the group policy settings rather than the remove+reinstall process. Worked like a champ. Thank you so much! :)